# FFT in R, obtaining values

Tags: r, fft

I have a generated data using 2 sines

```r
inputSignal <- 60000*sin(2*pi*(0.042)*x+4.5)+100000*sin(2*pi*(0.043)*x+3.3)
```

I want to retrieve this signal with FFT. I can do it graphically and locate the frequencies. How can I directly obtain the values for the frequency and amplitude and phase, without reading from a graph.

```
samplingFrequency <- 128
timeInterval <- 1/samplingFrequency
x<-c(0:1048575)*timeInterval
inputSignal <- 60000*sin(2*pi*(0.042)*x+4.5)+100000*sin(2*pi*(0.043)*x+3.3)
ffts <- fft(inputSignal)
freq <- c(0:(length(ffts)-1))*samplingFrequency/length(ffts)
plot(freq,abs(ffts)/(length(ffts)/2),type="h",xlim=c(0.042,0.043))
```

Comment: can you show us your FFT code?  `which.max()` will get you the index you need: you'll need to construct the frequency vector and use `mod()` and `atan2()` to get the amplitude and phase

Comment: Hello. I added my FFT code above. Wouldn't which.max() return only one of the amplitudes? I tried and got 1048576, which is close to 100000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the FFT of a real-valued signal is symmetric we'll take just the first half: (there is a more efficient algorithm for real-valued FFT that packs the real values into the components of a complex vector in such a way as to avoid the wastage. I don't know if it's implemented anywhere in R; I learned it long ago from Press et al. *Numerical Recipes*)

```
N <- length(ffts)/2
ind <- 1:ceiling(N)
af <- abs(ffts[ind])/N  ## or Mod(ffts[ind])
i <- which(af %in% rev(sort(af))[1:2])   ## find two max frequencies

ff <- ffts[i]/length(ind-1)
Mod(ff)
atan2(Im(ff), Re(ff))
freq[i]
```

This (or something like it) should be approximately right. I haven't double-checked all of my indices, quadrants, sin vs. cos, etc. (it's very likely that you remember the details of Fourier transforms better than I do ...)  If I've made mistakes, feel free to correct me in the comments.